# @selector in objective-c not behaving as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, callback, selector

I am a little perplexed and I have been working on this for hours and googling without any real leads. I want to create a callback in objective-c for my iPhone app utilizing the @selector.

Class 1:

```
- (void) someMethod {    
   // create selector
   SEL successCallback = @selector(successMethod);

   // call some service with caller and selector
   [class2 dispatchSomeEvent:self callback:successCallback];

   // here's the call back method
   - (void) successMethod {
      NSLog(@"Callback success");
   }
}
```

Class 2:

```
// some event
- (void) dispatchSomeEvent:(id) caller selector:(SEL) successCallback {
   // catch the event and execute callback
   if ([caller respondsToSelector:successCallback]) {
      [caller successCallback];
   } 
}
```

The conditional respondsToSelector will pass but the callback on the next line will fail. HOWEVER, if I would do like this:

```
// catch the event and execute callback
if ([caller respondsToSelector:successCallback]) {
   [caller successMethod];
}
```

So instead of using the selector I passed, I type in the method name directly... and it works!

The error I get is this:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6c37f70

What is going on here??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The compiler should be spewing a warning that caller does not respond to successMethod.

Comment: The callback `successMethod` should be giving you a syntax error if this code is verbatim.  You can't define methods inside other methods.

Answer (score 3):

You should call your selector using `-performSelector` method:

```
if ([caller respondsToSelector:successCallback]) {
  [caller performSelector:successCallback];
}
```